# Does Reuters provide the 4pm London Spot rate for currencies?

Tags: currency, foreign-exchange, online-data-source

The 4pm London spot rate is supposedly the standard, but I'm having trouble finding out if that's what I'm getting from Reuters.

First, I understand that currencies don't have just one exchange rate, since they're not centrally cleared.  So depending on where you're trading, there could be a different spot price.  So my interpretation of "4pm London spot" is the spot rate in London at 4pm GMT.  Is this correct?

If it is, then how do I find out if http://www.reuters.com/finance/currencies is giving me the London price?

Comment: quant.stackexchange.com maybe?

Comment: When I use the currency converter, it says "As of 05:00 EDT", even if I choose a prior date. I always understood 5pm EDT ("New York time") was the "start/end" of the "FOREX day". The "currency table" appears to have near-real-time prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation is correct. The Reuters may give you the London 4PM rates if you query after the close for the day. The close rate is treated as the rate. 
http://uk.reuters.com/business/currencies/quote?srcAmt=1&srcCurr=GBP&destAmt=&destCurr=USD

The London 4PM rate may be obtained from Bank of England at the link below;

http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/mfsd/iadb/index.asp?Travel=NIxSTxTIx&levels=1&XNotes=Y&XNotes2=Y&Nodes=X3790X3791X3873X33940&SectionRequired=I&HideNums=-1&ExtraInfo=false&A3836XBMX3790X3791.x=4&A3836XBMX3790X3791.y=3

Or any other Bank that provides such data